# Javascript - extract span value

Tags: javascript, html

Hi there i was wondering how you would get the Span Value="Example" from an object using JavaScript.

```
playlist = document.getElementById("list");
playlist.addEventListener("click",playNext,false);  

function playNext(){

var next = playlist.value;

    alert(next); }
```

As for the html

```
<span id="list" value="neededValue">Object1</span>
```

I am unable to extract the "neededValue" from this span object, however i have had success returning the innerHTML from this span.

Thanks,

Comment: Span elements do not have values. Only form input fields have a value. You're using a non-standard attribute. Don't do that.

Comment: Most browsers (but not all) do not make non–standard attributes available as properties. Use a [*data–** attribute](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/dom.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-*-attributes) (say *data–value*) or a class value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably want to use a data attribute to store the value. Here is a good article on what they are and how to use them http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/

Answer (score 1):

You need to use data-attributes, as a span don't has a value:

```
<span id="list" data-one="neededValue">Object1</span>

var a = document.getElementById('list');
alert (a.getAttribute('data-one'));
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/)

If you already have to many span elements with value, you can do it like this, but I would consider this as not good practice:

```
var a = document.getElementById('list');
alert (a.getAttribute('value'));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<span id="list" data-value="neededValue">Object1</span>


var playlist = document.getElementById("list");
playlist.addEventListener("click", playNext, false);  

function playNext(){
  var next = playlist.getAttribute("data-value");
  alert(next);
}
```