# javascript getAttribute stops the for loop

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop, getattribute

I'm doing a hangman game using only JavaScript HTML and CSS.
In one of my functions I try to take a span's attribute named: value_.
When the program reach that point, it runs once only. When I click on another letter it's not doing anything. If I put the getAttribute line in comments, the function run anytime I click on a letter.
Any ideas? :\

That's the code:

```
//Search and Update function after click
function search_(target, letter)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < randomWord.length; i++)
    {
        //Identify the <span>'s id by the letter
        var target_ = document.getElementById(letter + i);
        //Get the <span>'s value_
        var attr_ = target_.getAttribute('value_');
        alert(attr_);
        /*if (randomWord[i] == attr_)
        {   
          target_.className = 'hide';
        };*/
    };
};
```

Comment: Does the `value_` attribute exist? I wouldn't think it does, as it's not a standard HTML attribute. Also `span` elements don't have a `value`, please use `.textContent` instead.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27240889/javascript-extract-span-value

Comment: When I use the textContent the loop still return null on the second loop.
EDIT:
I gave it a data-value attribute, but the same happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright guys, I have changed a bit the function. Now it's working correctly.
Thank you for your help!

```
function search_(letter)
  {
    for (var i = 0; i < randomWord.length; i++)
    {
      //Identify the guessWord <span>
      var targetNew = document.getElementById(i + '' + (randomWord.length-i));
      //Make it appear if the word contain the clicked letter
      if (targetNew.getAttribute('data-value') == letter)
      {
        targetNew.className = 'hide';
      };
    };
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure this is what you want. But might consider a try :

```
function search_(target, letter) {
    for (var i = 0; i < randomWord.length; i++) {
        var target_ = document.getElementById(i); // you're not assigning span's id by letter, so this the way to get its id
        var attr_ = target_.innerText;
        console.log(attr_); // check console log
    };
};
```

**remember:** `<span>` element doesn't contain any `value/value_` attribute. so, to get a `<span>` element's value you should use `innerText` attribute.

Comment: I tried it with innerText , textContent and innerHTML too. When the loop steps into the next round it return a null and crash it.

Comment: then you must have an error somewhere else. consider creating a fiddle

Comment: When I use only this part:
function search_(target, letter)
  {
    for (var i = 0; i < randomWord.length; i++)
    {
      //Identify the <span>'s id by the letter
      var target_ = document.getElementById(letter + i);
      alert(target_);
    };
};

It run thought all of the span and give me the alert messages. If I try to get the value it crashes.

Comment: are you sure you getting the id `(letter + i)` correctly?

Comment: It should be good. It finds the span by the id. I'm using codepen you can check it there.

http://codepen.io/fekete965/pen/ggZBQz

Comment: remove `letter` just use `i` >> `document.getElementById(i)`